# React - how to render a map of field arrays (multiple responses to a single form question)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to figure out how to use react-hook-forms with field arrays. I have the form working (this code sandbox is where im testing changes to make this work: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-custom-input-7cdoh), but am now trying to figure out how to render the data.

I can log a json packet as:

```
"ethics": {
      "0": {
        "explain": "df",
        "managementPlan": "sdf"
      },
      "1": {
        "explain": "sdf",
        "managementPlan": ""
      },
      "value": "informedconsent",
      "label": "Informed consent"
    }
```

Then, in my display, I'm trying to loop through each array as follows:

```
{state.data.ethics.each.map(ethics => <Tag color="magenta">{ethics.label}</Tag>)}
```

This doesn't work - the error message says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

What do I need to do to present the output?

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the `ethics` object?

Comment: Yes im trying to loop to display the content of explain and managementPlan for each item in the array

Comment: But you don't have an array. You have an object. Could you be clear about what you want to display? Do you want to display the value of `explain` for each numbered key? Do you want to ignore `value` and `label`?

Comment: in item 0, i have an attribute called explain and another one called managementPlan. I want to display those as a group. Then I want to do the same for item 1. I am moving the label to the items so that each group has one and Ill deal with that in the same way

Comment: Gotcha. Do you have control over the shape of the json data?

Comment: yes - i think so - im just logging it to make sure im catching the form fields properly - but now im struggling to figure out how to render it

Comment: Then I would recommend formatting the data into an array. Then it would be much easier to map over it

Comment: It's a react-hook-form Field Array

Comment: @Mel Is state.data an array? If so, map over that. It would look like this: state.data.map(ethic => <Tag color="magenta">{ethics.label}</Tag>))

Comment: No - it produces a json packet in the form I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, you have a ethics object and not array.

```
 object.keys(state.data.ethics).map(k=>{
      const obj = state.data.ethics[key]; 
    /* your obj will look like below
    {
            "explain": "df",
            "managementPlan": "sdf"
          }
    */

     // Do Whatever you want to do with obj now 
     return (<>
         <div>{obj.explain}</div>
         <div>{obj.managementPlan}</div>
     </>)

    });
```